# Ion Auth update_user() does not update user

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, ion-auth

I'm trying to update an user with update_user function. But I have got this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception ‘Exception’ with message ‘Undefined method on_auth::update_user() called’

My code is

```
$id = 8;
$data = array(
     'first_name' => 'Ben',
     'last_name' => 'Edmunds',

      );
$this->ion_auth->update_user($id, $data);
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure this is the actual code that generates the error? Look at the error message: `on_auth`. It should be `ion_auth`. Search for typos.

Comment: I found the problem. I wanted to write here but I didn't allow me to wrote due to I am a new member :) So I can write as a comment. the coder of ion_auth didn't update documentation. So, instead of update_user , we should use just update. There are many more functions that he didn't update on documentation but have problems. I will write detailed explanation when stackoverflow allows me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem is the author didn't update user guide. Therefore, I had go through codes and found the solutions. In addition to that, this function is not the only function that should have changed in documentation. There are many. I hope he updates soon.

Solution

Instead of

```
$this->ion_auth->update_user($id, $data);
```

Use

```
$this->ion_auth->update($id, $data);
```